# Trying to download a zip file from a weblink with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Ok, I am trying to download a file off of a web link that we use with powershell.  I am downloading a zip file where the begining of the name is always the same, but the the middle part will change based off of the version number of the zip.  I have been able to get the file to download when I use the fully qualified web address and have the file name hard coded into the script.  I have tried every version of using the wild cards to get all the most common version of the zip, but it errors out saying that it can't find the file on there server.  This is the code that I have already, and any help would be greatly appreciated since I feel like I am at a wall with it.

```
$url = 'http://blah/blah/blah/My File Name 11.1111.11.zip'
$localFileName = 'C:\temp\MYzip.zip'

Invoke-WebRequest $url -UseDefaultCredentials -OutFile $localFileName
```

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest's documentation on -uri says that it unfortunately does not accept wildcards: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Adil, Is there another way to do this without using the Invoke-WebRequest in powershell?  I have been trying to find other ways but seem to be at a wall.

Comment: It's not a client limitation. A web server can't respond to a request for a wildcard - it needs a URL for a specific item on that server (consider the security implications of doing otherwise). You either need to know that version number ahead of time, or need a web page that your script can interrogate to find out what the filename is. You will have this limitation regardless of whether you use PowerShell, Python, cURL, wget, or any other method. Alternately, have the server provide a static URL which resolves internally to the "right" version of the file you need.

Comment: @alroc explained the problem. Is there anyway for you to enumerate list of files first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the site has directory browsing enabled (unlikely unless you have control of the site and can turn it on), you can do this:

```
$url = 'http://blah/blah/blah/'
$wr = iwr $url
$filename = $wr.Links.href | Where {$_ -match 'My File Name.*?\.zip'}
$wr = iwr "$url/$filename"
```

If the site doesn't have directory browsing enabled then surely it has a page with a link to the ZIP file on it.  Download that page and use the same `$wr.Links.href` trick to get all the links and look for the one that matches "My File Name.*?.zip".